# WPF RichTextBox seamless TextBoxes as InlineUIContainers

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm attempting to "Tokenize" text inside of a WPF RichTextBox control.  Whenever the user types a ";", the text before it is placed into a new TextBox contained within an InlineUiContainer. This allows the text to be programmatically different, and yet still be editable.

I was able to remove the border and make the background transparent so that the text looks to be directly inside of the RichTextBox, as desired; however, if you attempt to select only a portion of the text in a "token" and some text outside of it, the whole text box is selected regardless.

My question then is this: is there a way to make the textbox seamlessly selectable? and perhaps to make it so cursoring left/right with the arrows to move into the textbox rather than cursoring over it?

Comment: Why don't you insert a separate Run, instead of a TextBox?

Comment: I could possibly do that, althought I was looking for a good way to tell whether any given "Run" of text was already "tokenized" or not.  I suppose I could create a subclass `TokenizedRun : Run` and check based on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using an extension of the Run class.